# Per-Module Unit Testing in ZF2

Tags: php, unit-testing, configuration, zend-framework

This question is about handling namespaces and unit testing in ZF2.

Let's say I have a module called `Application`.  I have constructed `composer.json` to be like so

```
"autoload":{
   "psr-4": {
      "Application\\" : ["module/Application/src", "module/Application"],
   }
}
```

where first path is for the main code in the `src` folder as per PSR-4, and the second path is used access `test` namespace.

**What I get then is this directory structure:**

```
module
    /Application
        /public
        /src
            /Form
                Form.php  //namespace Application\Form;
            /test
                /Form
                    FormTest.php  //namespace Application\test\Form
        /test
            /Form
                FormTest.php  //namespace Application\test\Form;
```

This works, and seems to work both in Zend Studio, and in PHP-CLI (command line).  For `FormTest.php` class, the one in `src` gets priority despite both of them being in the same namespace.  I put them both just for an example that I can use either location.

Question:  I am concerned that having two paths in composer causes extra work for class name resolver, i.e when class is not found cleanly, in `src`, ZF2 does a lookup in `test`.

Can I improve the code?  Do I best use the `src` namespace only and move my `test` into `src/test` directory and namespace?  That is, get rid of `module/Application/test` folder and keep `module/Application/src/test`?  IS there a recommended best practices for this?

Comment: Migrated from Code Review because this is a specific best-practice question with hypothetical example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually keep `tests` and `src` completely independent, and not nested under each other.

Sources and test sources are typically defined like that.

In an application, I usually have following:

```
module
    /Application
        ...
        /src
            /Form
                Form.php // Application\Form\Form
        /test
            /unit
                /Form
                    FormTest.php // ApplicationUnitTest\Form\FormTest
            /integration
                /Form
                    FormTest.php // ApplicationIntegrationTest\Form\FormTest
tests
    /e2e
        /web
            ...
            LoginSeleniumTest.php // E2EWebTest\LoginSeleniumTest
```

Specifically, only unit tests are allowed inside modules. In some rare cases, I have a integration tests, but they should really be avoided as well as annotated with `@coversNothing`.

I adjust the `composer.json` to autoload each of these namespaces:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ApplicationUnitTest\\": "module/Application/test/unit",
            "ApplicationIntegrationTest\\": "module/Application/test/integration",
            "E2EWebTest\\": "tests/e2e/web"
        }
    }
}
```

What the IDE says here is completely irrelevant.